# How can I check if 2 drawn lines overlap?

Tags: python, tk-toolkit, overlap, turtle-graphics

I tried looking at the line-line intersection test but I don't quite understand it because it was using the endpoints of the line.

```
def lines(xcoord, ycoord):  
    penup()  
    goto(xcoord, ycoord)  
    pensize(3)  
    pendown()  
    color("blue")  
    forward(10)  
    right(randint(0,360))  
    penup()
```

So if I drew these lines randomly 10 times, how can I detect if any of them overlapped?

Comment: Have you looked into "Sweep Line Algorithm" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you understand how the line intersection test works, but you don't understand how you can apply it to your code, since you currently have no way to get the end points of your lines.

You should modify your `lines` method so that it returns the end points of the line it draws.

```
def lines(xcoord, ycoord):  
    penup()  
    goto(xcoord, ycoord)  
    startPoint = pos()
    pensize(3)  
    pendown()  
    color("blue")  
    forward(10)  
    right(randint(0,360))
    endPoint = pos()
    penup()
    return (startPoint, endPoint)
```

Then, when you are drawing the lines, keep track of the points:

```
myLines = []
for i in range(10):
    #not pictured: generate xcoord and ycoord however you want
    myLines.append(lines(xcoord,ycoord))
```

Later, you can detect which ones overlap, using the line-line intersection test that you looked at earlier.

```
def intersects(line1, line2):
    #todo: implement line-line intersection test that you read about

#iterate through all combinations of lines,
#testing whether the two intersect
for i, line1 in enumerate(myLines):
    for j, line2 in enumerate(myLines):
        #we don't care if a line intersects with itself
        if i == j: 
            continue
        if intersects(line1, line2):
            print "Line #{} intersects with Line #{}".format(i,j)
```